# Slick Carousel - Slider Image Shrinks on Mobile Resolution too much

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, slick.js

I'm trying to use the slick-Carousel for a large, and mobile version of a website using Foundation 6. I followed the the directions from the site, but it seems when i shrink my screen resolution down to a smaller (mobile) resolution the image is forced to shrink to 180px. The desired affect is for the slider to automatically size to the full-width of the view port.

I have three slick-Carousels on the webpage that are swapped out by using media queries. My mobile version is

My HTML markup is as simple as

```
<!-- Mobile Resolution -->
<div class="slider mobile_screen">
  <!-- Slide 1 -->
  <div class="design_services">
     <img src="http://www.advancedlitho.com/img/custom_images/mobile_slide_test.jpg" />
  </div>
  <!-- Slide 2 -->
  <div class="customer_service">
     <img src="http://www.advancedlitho.com/img/custom_images/mobile_slide_test.jpg" />
  </div>
  <!-- Slide 3 -->
  <div class="design_online">
     <img src="http://www.advancedlitho.com/img/custom_images/mobile_slide_test.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the site on a test server - http://nuspaservices.com/mobile_test/

I'm having a lot of trouble with this. So ANY help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Overwrite the CSS rule and give the slider a width of 100% at the mobile breakpoint that is causing issues.

Comment: Is this rule set somewhere within the Slick Carousel Jquery?

Comment: It will be in the CSS that comes packaged with the slider. Look for the media queries that impact the slider width. The query that applies to the mobile view that you are trying to alter - just change width to 100%. Make sure the `img` has 100% width and auto height set at that query point as well.

Comment: So far i think it has something to-do with the CSS within "foundation.css" and "slick-theme.css". Oddly there are no media queries in either of those style sheets. Something is conflicting. Haven't figured it out yet, hopefully soon. >< Oddly It only breaks at resolutions smaller than 499px...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its supposed to look like [this](http://screencast.com/t/wiYpLbO1JI) in tablet / mobile form.. Its missing atleast logo.css and logo.png and it looks nothing like the full size site.

That being said, maybe you can solve your resolution based issue with a custom media query.

```
@media (max-width:499px){
  .yourSelector{
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah the logo is not supposed to show at the moment on the test site, and Tablet view is not even set up yet. Just working on mobile for phones. But i am new to mobile design so i will try that out. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, okay - yeah its just conditional css depending on screen width. You can test it by dragging your browser window to the 500px mark to see what changes. I'd recommend doing something like setting the background-color to #f00 (red) at first to make sure the media query is working.